# How to update a field using a refresh timeout using JPA or SQL?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, jpa, mariadb

For a specific needs I want to set a table field auto updatable to value 0 after being set to 1 using a timeout which will be resetable if I do another update.

In my backend **SpringBoot Rest API** both JPA and JDBC are enabled and usable.

My DBMS is MariaDB.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 1000)
public void scheduleFixedDelayTask() {
    System.out.println(
      "Fixed delay task - " + System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
}
```

Spring has [built-in scheduler](http://www.baeldung.com/spring-scheduled-tasks) now. Previously people use Quartz library for that kind of purpose.

Comment: that a good thing to know but my issue is the timeout that i need it to be refreshable
in this case after 1000 my field will be 0 even if a do an update to value 1 at time 999

Comment: but finnaly this is not a bad idea i will make my schudle to minus the value by 5 for a specific rate or let it zero if is equal to zero, then for every update i will update my field to 5*timeout